# Set Call to PHP Function, with POST Variables as Parameters, as HTML Form Action

Tags: php, html, database, forms, function

I currently have an HTML file, with a form in it, that when submitted POSTs the form & calls a simple short PHP file that calls a function within another PHP file using the POSTed variables as parameters. The files are both below. What I am wondering is whether I can somehow skip the middleman PHP file, and simply call the function from my HTML file. 
Ideally, this would set the call to the function:

```
insert_PE(new PE($_POST[Date],$_POST[Participant],$_POST[Time],$_POST[Result],$_POST[Notes]));
```

as the form action. Does anyone know how/if this can be achieved?

HTML:

```
<FORM ID="FORM1" METHOD="POST" AUTOCOMPLETE="off" ACTION = "writeToDL.php">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="Date" STYLE="WIDTH:0px; " MAXLENGTH="8" TITLE="Enter Date" Value="<?php $dt = date('Y-m-d'); echo $dt ?>"/>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Time" STYLE="WIDTH:70px; " MAXLENGTH="7" ONCHANGE="validateTime();" />
    <SELECT NAME = "Result">
        <OPTION VALUE = OK></OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE = C>C</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
    <SELECT NAME = "Participant" STYLE = "WIDTH: 187">
        <OPTION SELECTED VALUE = "">Select...</OPTION>
            <?PHP
                $allParticipants = getall_participants();
                foreach($allParticipants as &$value) {
                    $val = $value->get_id();
                    echo "<OPTION VALUE='",$val,"'>";
                    echo $value->get_first_name()," ",$value->get_last_name();
                    echo "</OPTION>";
                }
            ?>
    </SELECT>
    <TEXTAREA NAME='Notes' COLS='28' ROWS='5'></TEXTAREA>
    <INPUT TYPE="image" SRC = "images/submit.png" VALUE="Submit Participant"/>
</FORM>
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
    include_once('database/PE.php');
    insert_PE(new PE($_POST[Date],$_POST[Participant],$_POST[Time],$_POST[Result],$_POST[Notes]));
?>
```

Comment: Hello, 1990 called and wants their uppercase HTML back... And no, you cannot skip PHP. HTML is purely a client-side thing, and cannot talk to a database in any way/shape/form. That's why there's PHP.

Comment: Why don't you make the HTML a PHP file, and call the insert method if the POST variables are set.

Comment: @MarcB I don't mean I want to get rid of the PHP entirely, but the small 3-line PHP file...It seems like I could probably combine it with the existing HTML file (that is actually a .php, though I primarily use HTML). And sorry, I'm a beginner with HTML, and this way the HTML tags stick out to me...Doesn't make a difference though, really. Not like clients are going to see it.

Comment: Joking aside, I agree with @MarcB - it's useful to standardise on a number of approaches, especially if other people will work with your code (now or in the future). Lower-case has been the norm for a good ten years I should think. Ditto using quotes for attributes rather than apostrophes (although I believe apostrophes still constitute valid (X)HTML).

Comment: Good point. I will take this into account.
As for the apostrophes, I try to only use them when there is PHP code, as PHP gets really fussy about apostrophes and quotation marks (you can't do """", but '""' or "''").

Comment: @RMartin - you can escape quotes with a backslash in PHP: `echo "<img src=\"cat.png\" />";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You COULD do something like this:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    include_once('database/PE.php');
    insert_PE(new PE($_POST['Date'],$_POST['Participant'],$_POST['Time'],$_POST['Result'],$_POST['Notes']));
} ?>
<html>
... rest of your page here ...
</html>
```

That way the PHP code only fires if an POST was actually performed. Some would suggest checking for the presence of a form field, but that's unreliable - you might change the form down the road and forget to update the `if()`. Checking the request method is guaranteed to be 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am wondering is whether I can somehow skip the middleman PHP file, and simply call the function from my HTML file.

No. The client only knows about URIs.

A URI can map to a PHP program. Multiple URIs can map to the same PHP program. You can use logic to determine what functions to run for a given URI. You can't avoid having that logic in your program.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put `method="_the_main_php_file_containing_function_to_be_called_"`

I hope it works fine.

Comment: And then try to make call in the main php file itself. If you are somehow unable to do this, then I think **you can not skip this middle file**

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a hidden field on the form, and populate it with the name of the function you want to run on "destination.php".  Then a switch statement on "destination.php" could pull the name of the function from POST variable.

Comment: Please demonstrate your answers.